# Deleting rows using stored procedure with parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I want to create a stored procedure that deletes from two tables using a paramater (id).

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_deleteDecision]
@ID int
AS

DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblDecisionInvolvement] as di
WHERE di.DecisionId = @ID
DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblDecision] as d
WHERE d.Id =@ID

GO
```

This is the error I get when I try to create it:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_deleteDecision, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_deleteDecision, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Note that changing the `DELETE FROM` to

```
SELECT * FROM
```

it works.

Is it even possible to delete something using parameters?

Ty.

Comment: Problem is alias, use alias only when you use joins...

Comment: Where did you see syntax that used `AS` in a delete this way? Did you look at [the official documentation for the `DELETE` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) when you encountered this error?

Comment: No, I was looking at the stored procedure page.
I did not realise that adding aliases was causing the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You aren't allowed to introduce an alias at that part of a `DELETE` statement - nor do you need one in this case:

```
USE ChessDb01
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_deleteDecision]
@ID int

AS

DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblDecisionInvolvement]
WHERE DecisionId = @ID
DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblDecision]
WHERE Id =@ID

GO
```

For a more complex query, you might want to use an alias, but note that (confusingly), the [`DELETE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) will have *two* `FROM` clauses - and you can only introduce the alias in the second one:

```
DELETE FROM di
FROM [dbo].[tblDecisionInvolvement] di
            inner join
      AnotherTable tab
           on
              di.Column = tab.Column2
WHERE tab.Column99 = @Value
```

Comment: I usually leave out the first `FROM` in your second example.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I removed the aliases and it works now. I feel relieved; thank you!

Comment: Aliasing can be used in Delete but it just over complicates it. Example Delete a from Table as a where column=@id